# Multi Language Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, multilingual, satellite-assembly

In My Project, there are different web pages and My requirement is when a User logs on based on user's language,page has to be displayed in user language.

I have googled it,but does not get proper solution.

I have got Satellite Asssemblies as a solution,but how to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MSDN documentation of ASP.NET localization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is good place to start reading about it. Basic steps are as follows:

1. Localize your web pages - these would create language specific resources that will yield satellite assemblies for supported languages.
2. Localize other aspects within application e.g. date/time formatting and input, images, user messages etc
3. Set the culture and UI culture within your web pages as per needs (e.g. based on browser settings or user preference or user selection etc.). See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for how to do it.

See [this walk-through](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that would quickly walks through basic steps.